# Code that only execute once, Python Startup folder

Tags: python, batch-file, directory, python-3.5, startup

Hey and thanks for all of your answers. I try to write a piece of python code that only executes once, (first time the program is installed) and copies the program into the windows startup folders.

(C:\Users\ **USER** \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup)

> That's the code i wrote for this. (Please don't judge me. I know it's
>   very shitty code. But I'm very new to coding. (this is the second
>   little program i try to write)

```
import os
import shutil


#get username
user = str(os.getlogin())
user.strip()

file_in = ('C:/Users/')
file_in_2 = ('/Desktop/Py Sandbox/test/program.py')
file_in_com = (file_in + user + file_in_2)

folder_seg_1 = ('C:/Users/')
folder_seg_2 = ('/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup')
#create FolderPath
folder_com = (folder_seg_1 + user + folder_seg_2)

shutil.copy2(file_in_com, folder_com)
```

> Because i got an error, that there is no such internal, external,
>   command, program or batch file named Installer. I tried to generate a batch file with
>   nothing in it that executes when the installation process is finished.(But the error is still there.)

```
save_path = 'C:/Windows/assembly/temp'
name_of_file = str("Installer")
completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".bat")
file1 = open(completeName, "w")
file1.close()
```

> The main idea behind this that there is my main Program, you execute
>   it it runs the code above and copies itself to the startup folder.
>   Then the code the whole installer file gets deleted form my main
>   program.

```
import Installer

#run Installer File
os.system('Installer')
os.remove('Installer.py')
```

But maybe there's someone out there who knows the answer to this problem. 
And as I said earlier, thanks for all of your answers <3.

BTW I'm currently using Python 3.5.

Comment: You should post the error message with the full stack trace.

Comment: C:\Users\Main\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe "C:/Users/Main/Desktop/Py Sandbox/Program/Program.py"
'Installer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys now I finally managed to solve this problem. It's actually not that hard but you need to think from another perspective.
This is now the code i came up with.

```
import os
import sys
import shutil

# get system boot drive
boot_drive = (os.getenv("SystemDrive"))

# get current Username
user = str(os.getlogin())
user.strip()

# get script path
script_path = (sys.argv[0])


# create FolderPath (Startup Folder)
folder_seg_1 = (boot_drive + '/Users/')
folder_seg_2 = ('/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup')
folder_startup = (folder_seg_1 + user + folder_seg_2)


#check if file exits, if yes copy to Startup Folder
file_name = (ntpath.basename(script_path))
startup_file = (folder_startup + ("/") + file_name)
renamed_file = (folder_startup + ("/") + ("SAMPLE.py"))


# checkfile in Startup Folder
check_path = (os.path.isfile(renamed_file))

if check_path == True:
    pass
else:
    shutil.copy2(script_path, folder_startup)
    os.rename(startup_file, renamed_file)
```

> This script gets your username, your boot drive, the file location of
>   your file than creates all the paths needed. Like your personal
>   startup folder. It than checks if there is already a file in the
>   startup folder if yes it just does nothing and goes on, if not it
>   copies the file to the startup folder an than renames it (you can use that if you want but you don't need to).

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to do an `os.getenv("SystemDrive")` or `os.getlogin()`, because `os.getenv("AppData")` already gets both. So the most direct way of doing it that I know of is this:

```
path = os.path.join(os.getenv("appdata"),"Microsoft","Windows","Start Menu","Programs","Startup")
```